# What are good materials to make an elastic and durable diaphragm, preferably with high stiffness?

Tags: materials, material-science, pistons

What are good materials to make an elastic and durable diaphragm, preferably with high stiffness to make a diaphragm or membrane pump for gas? Operating temperature will be between 0 and 100 degrees celsius and operating pressure of 15 bar.

Comment: Have you looked at pumps for this type of service and found out what current manufacturers use?

Comment: So once you decide the characteristics then check the material data sheets for those that can match.